# Resizing a Jpanel inside a Jframe at the same time

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, jpanel

I currently have a componentlistener on my jframe that repaints the jpanel when the window is resized, but only once the user lets go of the mouse. How can I alter my code so the panel will update at the same time the window is changed?

when the component listener detects resize it runs

```
    public void fitPanel(){
        if(spectrum!=null){
            spectrum.setStartPoint(new Point2f(0, 0));
            spectrum.setEndPoint(new Point2f(getWidth(), getHeight()));
            repaint();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a proper layout manager and the resizing will be done automatically and you don't even need the ComponentListener.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? I have layouts set to all panels and frame (I don't have explicitly set dimensions) so that the panels adjust on the first run. how can I have my panels readjust without calling some kind of method?

Comment: You don't do anything special. If you do the layouts properly, the components will resize automatically. Each LayoutManger has different rules for resizing so you need to mix and match layout managers to get your desired layout that will resize automatically. I have no idea what your frame looks like so I can't give a specific suggestion. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand how each layout manager works.